# Is there a way to test if the buffer might overflow (go above 2GB) before the write happens in a FlatBufferBuilder?

Tags: java, serialization, bytebuffer, flatbuffers

I am trying to use the `FlatBufferBuilder` Java API to serialize large amount of data (>100GB) into a sequence of size prefixed flatbuffers.

Is there a way to test if next write of a compiler generated `Table` object might give an `AssertionError` tied to growing above 2GB `ByteBuffer` size limit. There is an `int offset()` method but it doesn't account for alignment.

Furthermore, It's hard to extend the `FlatBufferBuilder` class since all the fields are private and only protected member is the `finish()` method

Does anyone know if its possible to perform this book-keeping to prevent possible buffer overflow ? I know we can't know size of every object beforehand but maybe a good hint can be taken from reusing some parts of this calculation

One possible simple solution could be to add a size cap of little bit less than 1GB possible using `offset()`. Since minimum alignment is the largest size of any object seen in the buffer, this would ensure it doesn't go above 1GB and total less than 2GB. I'm not sure if it might actually work. This doesn't require making any changes to the builder API.

I tried to do a infinite loop to write a `byte` value and it exits with an `AssertionError` tied to 2GB buffer size limit.

I looked at extending the `FlatBufferBuilder` but most of the members are private.

Comment: There is no way to know the exact byte size of a table you haven't written yet, so your best bet indeed is to stop adding data at a conservative limit well below 2GB.

Comment: Thanks for the response, it makes sense to keep it simple. I'll go with that for now. If I am able to determine any size bounds on the incoming objects, then I'll look into doing some size estimation or tracking.